# How to really "no-store" files in cache

Tags: http, caching, browser-cache

I wonder if there is a way to tell browser NOT to put entries of particular files in cache. I know that I can just send headers like no-store, Expires etc., but all those cause the entry to appear in cache anyway, though with past date.

I would like to know the solution that nothing appears in cache - I just don't want to litter the browser memory with hundreds of stale entries. For example, I don't want to cache png, so I use no-store no-cache, and in "about:cache" I see lots of information about this file, together with expiration date 1970-01-01 01:00:00. I would prefer not to see anything there with png extension, because I create hundreds of them in each session and they are needed only once, so I don't want to fill the cache with this junk.

I think that "no-store" should really not store, and instead it stores, but with past date!

Comment: Don't worry about "littering the browser memory". My browser(s) - I run 4 different ones - handles tens of thousands (if not hundreds of thousands) of different requests from my computer each day .. and they work like a champ. (However, *I'm not voting to close* because it would be interesting to see a detailed answer outlining the HTTP rules for clients as far as caching, and if a conforming server can instruct a client to not perform *any* cache bookkeeping. Any cacheable resource must, of course, get a cache entry in a conforming client.)

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no way to prevent the browser from storing the files in cache. no-cache instructs the browser to not use a stale version of the file, but it doesn't prevent it from storing the file.